# LINQ projection (Select) returning an odd result

Tags: c#, linq

**Consider the following code**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = default(int);

            IEnumerable<int> values1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 200)
                .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(100);

            IEnumerable<int> values2 = values1
                .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(50)
                .Select(o => { count++; return o; });

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Put a breakpoint on `Console.Read();`
2. Run to breakpoint
3. Inspect `count++` (should display 0)
4. Inspect `values2` and populate the Results View
5. Inspect `count++` (should display 100)

**Problem**

Given that I have only taken 50 items from `values1`, I would expect `count++` to display 50. Why does it display 100?

Please note, if this is confusing, try running this code instead, it produces the same result...

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = default(int);

            IEnumerable<int> values1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
                .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(50);

            IEnumerable<int> values2 = values1
                .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
                .Take(50)
                .Select(o => { count++; return o; });

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**

Inspect `count++`

[image]

Inspect `values2` (populate Results View)

[image]

Inspect `count++`

[image]

Any explanation as to what is happening here, and how to fix it?

**NOTE**

Many of the given answers suggest deferred execution. I know linq uses deferred execution, so unless I'm missing something, this is not the issue.

My point is that when the breakpoint is hit, the CLR has created a state machine for values2. Then this is iterated over in the debugger, count increments to 100 immediately for what appears to be only 1 iteration. This seems a little odd!

Also, I am aware that subsequent populations of the results view of value2 cause count to increment since this causes further iterations of the state machine.

Comment: The keyword to search is _deferred execution_. The debugger needs to evaluate the expression/query everytime you inspect it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter please see NOTE in question

Comment: The reason is that the debugger is evaluating this query twice. If you'd output it after an empty `foreach` you'd get the expected 50: `foreach (int i in values2); Console.WriteLine(count);`

Comment: Just to add to the last comment by @TimSchmelter, if you expand the query in the Locals / Watch / Quick Watch window, the query seems to be triple evaluated, leading to `count` 150 :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Every time you inspect `values2`, the expression is evaluated again -- and if you inspect it in the watch window, it appears to be evaluated *twice* each time (don't ask me why; ask the guys who wrote the watch window code). I got `count == 300`. Every time something evaluates it, it adds `50` to `count`; that's what the code does, see for yourself. And every time you expand it in the watch window, `count` increases by 100. Therefore, the watch window evaluates it twice.

You're only seeing one of those times, but so what? Lots of stuff goes on inside the VS code that it doesn't bother to show you. A GUI isn't a window into the internals of the program; it's a bunch of pixels on a screen that some code deliberately colored in. I could write a watch window that evaluates the expression nineteen times and shows you a Pokemon. What's the more plausible explanation: That some code you've never seen is doing something that doesn't happen to be shown in a GUI, or that sometimes your computer can't add?

Look at the runtime type of `values2`: `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<int, int>`. That's no collection, that's something that's waiting to execute.

Let's add `ToList()` to the end of that expression. That'll evaluate it once and store the results. Then you can inspect the results all day long without executing any LINQ expressions again.

```
int count = default(int);

IEnumerable<int> values1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 200)
    .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Take(100);

IEnumerable<int> values2 = values1
    .OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Take(50)
    .Select(o => { count++; return o; })
    .ToList();
```

Now `count == 50`, because the expression is only evaluated once, and the results are stored in a `List<T>`.

### Moral of the story:

The dots on the screen are an illusion, and combining lazy evaluation with side effects is like setting a monkey loose in Starbucks with a machine gun. I'm not saying it's *wrong*, it's just not everybody's idea of a fun date.

Comment: I understand that, but, expanding the results view causes an iteration of the state machine. This is evident since the results are always different due to the behaviour of OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()) - I want to know why count is 100 for only 1 iteration?

Comment: @series0ne If `count == 100`, it's not only one iteration. Which is more reliable: Your (or my!) intuition about how many times a linq expression was evaluated by the watch window (of whose internals I know absolutely nothing), or a computer doing arithmetic? Try adding `ToList()`, to *guarantee* exactly one single iteration. When I do that, I see `count == 50`.

Comment: I understand that .ToList() guarantees exactly one iteration, however, I want to know why on inspection of "what appears to be the first and only" iteration, count increments to 100?

Comment: @series0ne: btw,  you can simplify your example: even this query will return 100 as count in the debugger: `IEnumerable<int> values1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(o => { count++; return o; });`. So neither the `OrderBy` nor the `Take` or the second query are related. Only the fact that the debugger does more than you have expected. If you would output the count after `foreach (int i in values1); Console.WriteLine(count);`, you would get 50 as result. It's the debugger

Comment: @series0ne it is not related to to `OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid())`. just comment it and test. same result again.

Comment: @series0ne The only accurate information you have about the number of evaluations is the value of `count`, which is telling you plain as day that there were *two* evaluations. You know exactly what you're doing to `count`; that's an absolute known certainty. The internals of the watch window are a wild guess. Yeah, it doesn't *look* to you like it enumerated that sequece twice; you didn't *see* the watch window doing that; but why would it have to do that where you can see it? It's code. It can do all kinds of stuff, and the UI shows you only what it shows you.

Answer (score 3):

It is because Linq is executed as **deffered**, until you explicitly call `ToList()`, or iterate the result, the delegate will not be invoked.

When you view the result of the Projection in quick watch, at that time the delegated is invoked to populate the results as @Ed also mentioned.

Comment: Yes and no. No, because then you should see 50 anyway after the first enumeration, but that's clearly not the case. You always get 100 even with this query: `var x=Enumerable.Range(1,50).Select(i=>count++)`. So by evaluating it in the debugger quick watch window you will already execute it twice. Yes, because deferred execution is still responsible for this issue.

Comment: agreed @TimSchmelter, it is a delegate, it can be invoked as many times as you want to